# jQuery AJAX pass form data and an array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass some HTML form data as well as a global array to PHP via AJAX. I know how to pass an array, and I know how to pass serialized form data. But how do I pass both at the same time? I have tried data: { formData, arrGFormId: arrGFormId }, but it doesn't work.

Edit: The form is just a simple HTML form with some inputs. My array values come from another AJAX call and are pushed into the global array arrGFormId.

```
function validateForm3(){

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "community_form_add.php",
    async: false,
    data: { arrAdminList: arrAdminList },
    }).done(function(rs){
    var sResult = rs.sResult;
    var arrFormId = rs.arrFormId;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(arrGFormId, arrFormId);

  })        
})

var arrGFormId = [];

jQuery('#formCreateForm').submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault(); 

var formData = new FormData(jQuery(this)[0]); 

formData.append('sAction', 'submitForm');
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'community_form_add.php',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend:function(){

        jQuery('.load_ball').css("display","block"); 
    },  
    success: function(data)
    {   
            jQuery('.load_ball').css("display","none");
            jQuery('.cover').css("display","block");
            jQuery('.popUpSubmitSuccess').fadeIn(300);
    }       
})
});
```

Comment: could you give more details about the files/scripts related to your `formData` or array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode the array, then you can add it to the `FormData`. You can convert it to JSON.

```
formData.append('arrGFormId', JSON.stringify(arrGFormId));
```

Then in PHP you can use `json_decode($_POST['arrGFormId'])`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden input inside the existing form. the value of the hidden inputs are the array. so you only pass `formData` through ajax.